# Giving an error saying local variable is not assigned

Tags: c#, variables

This is a simple code I have written to solve a mathematical problem.

```
namespace StoreCredit
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int No1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"input.txt");

            int nocases = int.Parse(text[0]);
            int J = 1;
            int No1=0;
            int No2=0;
            for (int x = 1; x <= nocases;x++ )
            {
                int Amount = int.Parse(text[J]);
                int NoItem = int.Parse(text[J+1]);

                char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };

                string[] Values = text[J+2].Split(delimiterChars);

                int z = 0;
                bool found = false;
                while ((z < NoItem) && !found)
                {
                    int Item = int.Parse(Values[z]);

                    int Remaining = Amount - Item;

                    int y = 0; bool found2 = false;
                    while ((y < NoItem) && !found2)
                    {
                        if (Remaining == int.Parse(Values[y])&&!(y==z))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Found a match");
                            found = true;
                            found2 = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Value 1 = {0} and Value 2={1}",(z+1),(y+1));
                        }
                        y++;
                    }

                    z++;
                }

                string lines = "Case #" + x + ": ", z, y;
                StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"output.txt", true);
                file2.WriteLine(lines);
                file2.Close();

                J = J + 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to write the out put of this program to a text file. But I get an error saying z,y  cannot be declared in this scope because it would give an different meanings to z,y. Can you please explain me the reason for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line near the end attempts to re-declare `z` and `y`, since you've separated them by commas:

```
string lines = "Case #" + x + ": ", z, y;
```

Did you intend to concatenate them instead? Such as:

```
string lines = "Case #" + x + ": " + z + y; // notice the + instead of comma
```